# Nginx server block that serves http2 without other http and without https

Tags: nginx, http2

I am trying to host a website that only allow user to enter the website http://website.com:1234 using direct http2, and do not allow any users to enter via http0.9, http1.0, http1.1 or upgrade from either one of them. Additionally, I do not want my website to be able to serve https.

I have tried to configure using:
server {

```
listen 1234 ssl http2
listen [::]:1234 ssl http2
etc
etc
```

}

as well as
server {

```
listen 1234 http2
listen [::]:1234 http2
etc
etc
```

}

It does not work like how I wanted to, could anyone be able to help me?

Comment: You should probably try with just the second `server` block, and test the `$http2` variable for the value `h2c`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#var_http2).

Comment: @RichardSmith how can i test that? I'm actually quite unfamiliar regarding this. Could you guide me?

So you mean by using this, am i right?
server {

listen 1234 http2
listen [::]:1234 http2
etc
etc
}

Comment: And is there any way to do without h2c? Because I am trying to not upgrade from other http request, as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is not technically possible.

No browsers currently support http2 without encryption and unencrypted http2 connections require an upgrade from http 1.1 according to the spec

See [here](https://http2.github.io/faq/#can-i-implement-http2-without-implementing-http11) and [here](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption) for more info

Comment: This is not 100% accurate. While browsers only support HTTP/2 over HTTPS there are other non-browser clients (though suspect you are correct and OP is most likely talking about browsers). Unencrypted HTTP/2 connections can be connection to straight to HTTP/2 with prior knowledge method if you know that server talks HTTP/2 (again for non-browser usage): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.4. Looks like that FAQ needs a little editing.

Comment: Hi @milknik, yes it is as what Barry had said, I'm trying to do unencrypted HTTP/2 connection connect straight to HTTP/2. Using that link that you have send to me, I have some issues understanding. They stated, "Can I implement HTTP/2 without implementing HTTP/1.1?
Yes, mostly." 
Wouldn't that mean I'm able to do it?

Comment: As king as you don’t want to use a browser and your non-browser client supports h2c and prior knowledge. If you want to do it from a browser then no it’s not possible.

Comment: @BarryPollard Hi, so currently i have decided to keep it to the minimal and just use http2 in my server block. But I can't view it in my google chrome, only on IE i am able to do it. However, it is in binary. Is it normal?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand what you’re asking? Are you using https?